# Expert “in” or “on”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, phrase-meaning, difference

I saw in a textbook,

> “He studied the slipperiness of banana peels. (...) He is an expert **in** medical science.”

I have seen “expert on —-“ many times but this is the first time I saw “expert in —-“.

“Expert on” is understandable for me because “on” is often used like “a book on animals”, which shows that the book is for specialists of animals.

When I looked up the word in a dictionary, the word “expert” is used even with “at” and “with”.

Is there any difference between these combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expert *at/in* are common and, we can find many examples from authentic sources like dictionaries' sample examples. This means both are correct and it ***may depend on the writer's style*** to choose the preposition. Expert ***on...*** something is also correct but I think it's not **that** common. And, so is *expert **with...***

Nevertheless, if I read between the lines, I may prefer using *expert **in...*** if I'm talking about some field.

> He's expert **in** medical science

On the other hand, if I'm talking about some *procedure/process,* I may use *expert ***at...***

> He's expert **at** robotic surgery

Note that this is just my two cents and **not** a rule.

Comment: Your example sentences are good.  They show how many native speakers would use **in** with a subject area and **at** with a skill.

Comment: ...and 'on' with a topic: "Italy's top expert on Leonardo da Vinci, died at his villa
outside Pistoia on Friday."

Comment: @JeremyC Can I make this clear? You mean da Vinci is an object of research in this sentence?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly right. Leonardo daVinci is not a 'subject area' (where 'in' would be right) or a 'skill' (where 'at' might be right).